# Lock file permission to 'disallow download'

Tags: box-api

I'm writing a Box App for enterprise use. The scenario is the application scans the user account, and changes the permission of certain file (which we believe it's sensitive) to 'disallow download'. Good thing is it can be done, however, when user logins, he/she can easily change the permission back to 'allow download' from webpage. Is there any way to prevent user changing the permission back? Any idea?

Comment: what you do till explain some code or snapshots with detailed information

Comment: @user3011701 Can you be more descriptive about what your app is trying to do in terms of preventing a download? Are you looking to prevent a download from a logged in user who has access to the file, or a user that has access to the file via a shared link? Box has implemented the lock feature to be a signal to users that someone is editing it, not a mechanism to keep users from downloading or modifying it - other Editors of the file can unlock the file, if they wish to. Other applications that need to truly quarantine a sensitive file will move it and leave something else in its place.

Comment: Also, lock/unlock is not yet documented but is working. You can do a PUT on a file with the request body of... {"lock":{"status":"lock", "expires_at": "2013-12-01T16:51:19-08:00", "is_download_prevented":false}}. To unlock it set the request body to... {"lock":null}

Answer (score 0):

Lock unlock functionality is coming soon in the V2 API.  Stay tuned for a blog post in the next week or so.